# Gimp canvas resize through terminal

Tags: terminal, gimp

I have multiple images in wrong canvas sizes and I need to resize them like this:

```
for i in *; do blabla $i -resize 500x500 $i; done
```

I can already resize image with convert tool but I need to resize the canvas of gimp.

Answer (score 1):

Would the "-extent" parameter work here ?

http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#extent